# Android example needed for sending mail via SMTP from oAuth authenticated app

Tags: android, oauth, smtp, gmail

I am following a demo for oAuth that retrieves a users Gmail Contacts. I can authenticate via oAuth and getting the contacts works just fine.

Now I want to modify this to be able to send an email via SMTP. I can get oAuth authorization to do this just fine.

My problem is that I can't figure out the next step. How do I format the request to send an email once I am authenticated.

I don't expect anyone to write the code for me, just a simple link to the google api docs that cover this should get me going. I just can't seem to find them.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looking into this further I am starting to think that once I have authenticated via oAuth that I will then need to use an external library like javamail to then send the email and somehow pass the oAuth credentials.

Can someone confirm this for me and maybe point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually been researching on this too. If you can authenticate via OAuth, then you'll just need Google's API for Gmail via OAuth to get it working. I got Gmail working with OAuth as a java application. For Android though, it's funny that the same code Google provided only works for SMTP (not IMAP). But I guess it'll still help.

The following link will get you to Google's OAuth protocols for Gmail:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview
They have sample ready to use. Make sure you have JavaMail and the OAuth access token ready. You don't need Apache Ant to run their sample code though. I just used eclipse and ran the main class.

Also know that OAuth for Gmail is slightly different. I'm not sure how you're doing the authentication, but for Gmail the **SCOPE** will be different: https://mail.google.com/ In case you don't know about it, **Scribe** would be an extremely convenient way to get OAuth working in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnPreviewEmails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          String host="your smtp";
          final String user="from email address";//change accordingly
          final String password="frm email password";//change accordingly

          String to="to email";//change accordingly

           //Get the session object
           Properties props = new Properties();
           props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);
           props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

           javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                      protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(user,password);
                      }
                    });

                   //Compose the message
                    try {
                     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
                     message.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
                     message.setSubject("javatpoint");
                     message.setText("This is simple program of sending email using JavaMail API");

                    //send the message
                     javax.mail.Transport.send(message);

                     System.out.println("message sent successfully...");

                     } 
                    catch (MessagingException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
    }});
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to do this without having to ask user for credentials.

Comment: This is not a valid answer, the question is about OAuth2 Authentication which does not use user name and password, instead use Oauth token. Please read about Google and OAuth. I have down voted the answer to avoid misguiding developers. Your answer may be fine for Non OAuth however Google blocks email sent via unsecured apps, unless user takes the risk which is not a safe method.